# Meaning of もらってもらう?

Tags: grammar, giving-and-receiving

I found the combination "もらってもらう" in a text in 新完全文法N1, page 142:

> 「これ、もらってくれるとありがたいんですけど……。」と言って、わたしによく服を譲ってくれる友人がいる。彼女がもう着ない服だ。自分が要らない服を人に**もらってもらう**のは、意外に難しい。二人がとても親しくて、服の好みが合っている場合に限る。

My questions are as follows:

- What does this expression mean as a whole?
- How can you break down the expression to explain its meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

もらう/いただく are usually translated as "receive".
もらう/いただく can also be used as an auxiliary verb when someone does something for you.
The subject of the sentence is usually the speaker (私) and can be omitted.

Example:

私は彼に書いてもらう。
He writes for me.
Literally: I receive from him the act of writing.

So in the following sentence, the first もらう　means "receive".
But the second もらう is an auxiliary verb.
服を人にもらってもらう
To have people accept my clothes.
Literally: to receive from people the act of receiving my clothes.

More details can be found in "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar", page 263.